# Adding information to a column conditionally comparing strings

Tags: r

I have a data frame called "grass". One of the information in this data frame is "Line" which can be: high, low, f1, f2, bl or bh.

I created a new column and want to add information to this column as the following code shows.

The problem is that I get "1" for all, not just for "high"

```
#add new column
grass["genome.inherited"] <- NA

#adding information to genome.inherited 
#1 for the high-tolerance parent genotype (high)
#0 for the low-tolerance parent genotype  (low)
#0.5 for the F1 and F2 hybrids (f1) (f2)
#0.25 for the backcross to the low tolerance population (bl)
#0.75 for the backcross to the high tolerance population (bh)

#how I tried to solve the problem
grass$genome.inherited <- if(grass$line == 'high'){
    1
} else if(grass$line == 'low'){
    0
} else if(grass$line == 'bl'){
    0.25
} else if(grass$line == 'bh'){
    0.75
} else {
    0.5
}
```

As suggested here is the output for head(grass)

```
line cube.root.height genome.inherited
high             4.13                1
high             5.36                1
high             4.37                1
high             5.08                1
high             4.85                1
high             5.59                1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Consider adding the output of `dput(head(grass))` to your post. Can't help much without looking at some data.

Comment: @Isabela I see all `high` in the `line` that's why all are 1 ?

Comment: @YOLO I am only showing the output of head(grass), and the first ones showing are high.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning when you passed grass$line to the `if` function. That's not a proper use of `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to create a new column with NA. Here is the code which does it for you.

```
grass$genome_inherited_values <- ifelse(grass$line == 'high', 1,
                  ifelse(grass$line == 'low', 0,
                         ifelse(grass$line == 'bl',0.25,
                                ifelse(grass$line == 'bh',0.75,0.5)
```

Comment: Nested `ifelse` constructions are rather slow.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `match` function. It gives a number that indicates the position of a value in a character vector and has an "nomatch" value as well.

```
grass$genome.inherited <- c(1, 0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5)[ 
                        match( grass$line, c( 'high', 'low','bl','bh'), nomatch=5) ]
```

Example from console with other values of line to test:

```
 grass <- read.table(text="line cube.root.height genome.inherited
 high             4.13                1
 high             5.36                2
 low             4.37                1
 high             5.08                1
 junk             4.85                1
 high             5.59                1
 ", head=T)

 grass$genome.inherited <- c(1, 0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5)[ 
                       match( grass$line, c( 'high', 'low','bl','bh'), nomatch=5) ]
 grass
#----
  line cube.root.height genome.inherited
1 high             4.13              1.0
2 high             5.36              1.0
3  low             4.37              0.0
4 high             5.08              1.0
5 junk             4.85              0.5
6 high             5.59              1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` conditions have length > 1. When the condition has length > 1 only the first element will be used and that's why you are getting all `1`s.

Here's a different (simpler than nested `ifelse`) approach for the same thing -

```
vals <- c(high = 1, low = 0, f1 = 0.5, f2 = 0.5, bl = 0.25, bh = 0.75)

grass$genome.inherited <- vals[as.character(grass$line)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree (with 42-) that nested `ifelse` statements is not preferred. @42-'s solution of `match` is (imo) far better than `ifelse`s.

An alternative is to `merge` them.

Data:

```
grass <- read.table(text="line cube.root.height
 high             4.13
 high             5.36
 low             4.37 
 high             5.08
 junk             4.85
 high             5.59
 ", head=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The table of values to merge in:

```
genome <- data.frame(
  line=c("high","low","bl","bh"),
  genome.inherited=c(1, 0, 0.25, 0.75),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The merge:

```
grass2 <- merge(grass, genome, by="line", all.x=TRUE)
```

If you look at the data, you'll see an `NA`, because `"junk"` (an unknown value) is not present in the `genome` table and therefore assigned as `NA`. We can fix this with an easy step:

```
grass2$genome.inherited[is.na(grass2$genome.inherited)] <- 0.5
grass2
#   line cube.root.height genome.inherited
# 1 high             4.13              1.0
# 2 high             5.36              1.0
# 3 high             5.08              1.0
# 4 high             5.59              1.0
# 5 junk             4.85              0.5
# 6  low             4.37              0.0
```

@42-'s answer has the advantage of providing a default (`nomatch`) value in the initial call.